# Fade-out fade-in animation sequentially

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to animate through javascript and CSS a simple fade-out fade-in animation. I create a simple animation in CSS, like follows:

```
@keyframes fade-in{
0%{
  opacity: 0%;
}
100%{
  opacity: 100%;
}
}


@keyframes fade-out{
0%{
  opacity: 100%;
}
100%{
  opacity: 0%;
}
}
```

Then I have this simple script where I read the section i want to go to display none and the other to display grid with the animation in between:

```
function changeDisplay(section){

for(i=0;i<section.length;i++){
    if(window.getComputedStyle(section[i]).display == 'grid'){
            if(i+1 == section.length){
                section[i].style.animation = 'fade-out 500ms'
                section[i].style.display = 'none'
                section[0].style.display ='grid'
                section[0].style.animation = 'fade-in 500ms'
                
                break;
            }
    }
}
}
```

The code functions right, the previous section goes to display none and appears the next section with display grid. The problem is that only the last animation appears, I mean, i can only see how it fades-in after displaying none without animation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain the reason for the loop.  It appears to executes code only on the last element, which makes it unnecessary.

Comment: I'm doing a slider of images. I have like 10 sections where only the current one is visible. When sliding to the right, the current section goes display:none, and the next goes to display grid. I didnt include the rest of the code inside that loop because isn't relevant for the problem of the animation.

Comment: Yeah, it's true that the setTimeout doesn't work properly, the opacity transition works fine

Comment: It works properly if you know JS, it's just that it is running in the async tasks queue. Use `opacity` + `transition` instead of `animation` and voila.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the animation to end to set `display: none`, otherwise your transition wont have time to run.

```
section[i].style.animation = 'fade-out 500ms'
setTimeout(() => {
  section[i].style.display = 'none'
  section[0].style.display ='grid'
  section[0].style.animation = 'fade-in 500ms'
}, 500);
```

Imho a better way to do this is to simply give `transition: opacity 500ms` to your section and set `opacity: 0` or `opacity: 1`.
When using your technique your element might bleep after the animation is done at runtime. The reason is `setTimeout(() => action, 500)` does not guarantee that the action is taken precisely 500ms after previous code because of potential code running in between.